# Email Response Program

Tags: database, email

I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction. I'm pretty new to this, so forgive the newbyness.

I want to creat an auto response email based on what product my customer shows interest in. For example, if I fill out a form on a car dealership website for their Internet Pricing...I get an email telling me what  that price is.

Right now when a customer fills out a form I receive an email as administrator that tells me the make, model and stock number.

I'm thinking I want to build a program that can recognize that stock number, affiliate it with a vehicle in a database along with the Internet price and return that value via an Email to the customer.

What direction should I go? Where should I start? Like I said I'm pretty new at this. I would maybe even be willing to hire this out if it's too overwhelming. Thank for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Without any form of disrespect or anything - it probably is a wise idea to hire someone :) 
you need to learn about databases, about using for example ASP.NET to develop the website, HTML/CSS for the layout of the website. you need to purchase products like Visual Studio which contains everything you need to start developing your idea/website and also the database engine like SQL Server. It really depends on what your current environment is like (i.e what database engine you are using) and what platform you want to use to develop your idea. This is pretty simple stuff from what you are describing to do but it sounds like you don't know how to start to develop simple code/software.... that's all. I am sure you can do it but requires a lot of training/teaching for you to "get there" :)

Comment: Sorry, to clarify the website is already built. And the ability to fill out the form is done too. We have a company who made it for us. But they are a big automotive company and they didn't put that ability in there. I thought maybe there would be a way to still use the lead email to send a reply the user. Does that make sense?

Comment: kind of. if the website is already built then you should have the code for it, right? if not - then you need to get it from them or ask them to make the changes you want made. But if they cannot do that and you have the code, you then need to take it to someone who understands the code (the site for all we know could be ASP.NET or ASP or php or something) who can then make the changes you want. It is possible - you just need hold of the code